# Columns width of array environment

Tags: arrays, width

I'm using the `array` environment and have something like this:

```
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
   \hline 
   \textbf{x} & \textbf{y} \\ 
   \hline
   \hline
   t_1 & lon_1 \\ 
   \hline 
\end{array}
```

I would like to have the two columns to have the same width. How can I do that?

Comment: One way would be to use `p{1.0cm}` as in `\begin{tabular}{|p{1.0cm}|p{1.0cm}|}`, which necessitates the content being in math mode: `$t_1$`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Good point. I dislike this solution as you have to fix the width, and have to do additional tweaking if you want to switch from `l`, to `c` to `r` alignment, but only mentioned it as an option.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you don't want to use the the `p{<width>}` column type where you have to fix the width to a specific amount you could typeset one row using the `SetToWidest` macro as defined below.  This requires that you determine what the widest entry is and define that as the value of `WidestEntry`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\WidestEntry}{$lon_1$}%
\newcommand{\SetToWidest}[1]{\makebox[\widthof{\WidestEntry}]{#1}}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
   \hline 
   \textbf{x} & \textbf{y} \\ 
   \hline
   \hline
   \SetToWidest{$t_1$} & $lon_1$ \\ 
   \hline 
\end{tabular}
```

or similarly using `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\WidestEntry}{$lon_1$}%
\newcommand{\SetToWidest}[1]{\makebox[\widthof{\WidestEntry}]{$#1$}}%

\begin{document}$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
   \hline 
   \textbf{x} & \textbf{y} \\ 
   \hline
   \hline
   \SetToWidest{t_1} & lon_1 \\ 
   \hline 
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

---

If you are ok with specifying the width of each column you can use the `p{<width>}` column type:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}$
\begin{array}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash$} p{1.0cm} <{$} | >{\centering\arraybackslash$} p{1.0cm} <{$} |}
   \hline 
   \textbf{x} & \textbf{y} \\ 
   \hline
   \hline
   t_1 & lon_1 \\ 
   \hline 
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```